# Does the legacy token aka internal oauth token ever expire?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, oauth2, fuel-sdk

https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/marketing-cloud-apps/single-sign-on.html describes the `request->user->internalOauthToken` as:

> An OAuth2 token that can access Email SOAP API. It is also referred to as the legacyToken in the Fuel API Family (REST). For more information please review the OAuth And SOAP API page.

Does this token ever expire?  Does it require refreshing?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It expires after one hour, so yes you will need token refreshing.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere? I found documentation that says 1 hour for the non-legacy token `user.oauthToken` (on the page linked above, in the attribute description), but are both affected?  Do you have to refresh the token within the 1 hour, or anytime? Does the refreshed token itself expire after 1 hour?

Comment: Look a few lines down in the documentation:  "Length in seconds before tokens expire. Value of 3600 is equal to 1 hour for example."

Comment: Thanks!  I guess the plural "tokens" implies what I need.  ;)  If I refresh for an offline token, does that new one last forever?

Comment: This example code never refreshes the internal token, implying that maybe it does not require it after all?  https://github.com/ExactTarget/SubscriberSearch-rub/blob/master/helpers/rest.rb

Comment: I've never actually used the internal token, so I cannot comment.

Answer (score 0):

Desired path is to use the oAuth access token and not the legacy token.

I wrote a post on how to do this - http://www.kellyjandrews.com/2014/02/20/using-fuel-oauth-with-the-soap-api.html

Basically replace your header with the following:

```
<Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">YOURACCESSTOKEN</fueloauth>
</Header>
```

Grab the access token as normal, and use here.  Legacy Tokens still work, but they will probably go away in the future, and this will save you headaches later.

Comment: Note that as of this writing, Ruby FuelSDK (at least) uses the legacy token for many operations.